# c# dice simulation program

Tags: c#, forms, dice

I have a homework from school, but i really dont know how can i do this, i think im really bad at programming. So i need your help.
The homework:

- It is possible to specify the number of cubes ( 1...6 )
- the type of cubes (page number) (4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
- If i click to button the program will generate the  cube throw and it will show in the screen
- The settings are stay between throws
- The first two cubes let dragging maths into it be an opportunity. The two cubes give his throw result, multiplies it, you are it first one multiplies 10-away, and adds it to it
  Thank you!

Comment: so what is the code you have done? when you speak about type of cubes its number of sides?

Comment: Yes, when i spoke about type of cubes its number of sides, sorry my english is really bad.I was thinking,how I would be able to make it but i did not realise it

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's only one type of _cube_ - and it has 6 sides.  Did you mean "dice" just about everywhere you said "cubes"?

Answer (score 0):

I just give you the Start of idea, the method which returns a throw of each dice whatever the number of sides. the return values are inside a list, index 0 for first dice , index 1 for next and so on following the number of dices

```
public List<int> DiceThrow(int dicesNbr, int sidesNbr)
{
    var resultPerDice = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dicesNbr; i++)
    {
        resultPerDice.Add(Random.Range(1, sidesNbr + 1));
    }

    return resultPerDice;
}
```

to you for the end of your job